# Is there a semantic description of gramps data.xml?

Tags: gramps, data-transfer

I would like write data (export from my program) to gramps data.xml but i don't understand the semantic of gramps export format. For example:

- people home attribute refers to ?
- person change attribute refers to?
- timestamps are milliseconds with begin at?

([DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) is known)

[Update analysis results]

My guess based on [gramps example](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/blob/master/example/gramps/data.gramps):

- handle of person is referenced by person@child, person@father, person@mother.
- handle of familie is referenced by person@parentin
- change is a timestamp miliseconds since ??? year.
- people@home is a reference to a person@handle

Comment: (Caveat: I'm not a Gramps user, and this is the first time I've looked at it.) Gramps has some pretty thorough documentation, but it doesn't seem to describe the XML format clearly. The XML looks like a dump of the internal [database](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_database_API), and that's probably where to start. For example, under [Table Objects](https://gramps-project.org/docs/gen/gen_lib.html#table-objects) it notes that times are in the python time.time() format, which counts fractional seconds since the "epoch", which is 1970/01/01 00:00:00 on my Windows PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to view how Gramps writes its own [XML file](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/blob/master/gramps/plugins/export/exportxml.py)

Another is to join the Gramps developers mailing list and ask.

I don't believe many of the developers are here

Also see:

- RDDL Directory for [GRAMPS XML format 1.7.1](https://gramps-project.org/xml/1.7.1/)